# css / html - remove space before li tag

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the space (marked as yellow) before the li tag and i don't know how.

I read other questions about this issue but it doesn't help me, I tried to add margin:0px

this is a  screenshot that describes the problem:

[image]

```
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<style type="text/css">

*
{
    font-size:13pt;
    font-family:Arial;
}

hr {
border:1px; Border-Style: solid; border-color: D8D8D8;
}

.menu ol,ul{list-style:none; }
.menu ul li{    display:block; }

.menu{
}
.menu a{
    background:#f9f9f9;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    display:block;
    padding:13px;
    color:#767676;
    font-size:12px;
}
.menu a:hover{
    background:#fff;
}
header .menu{
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
}
header .menu a{
    padding:15px 15px 15px 25px;
}
header .menu li:last-child a{
    border-bottom:none;
}


a:link, a:visited, a:active {color: #033254 } 
a:hover{color:E19E21} a{text-decoration:none}
</style>
<body bgcolor='#FDFDF7' leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">


            <ul class="menu">


<li><a href="eeee">aaaaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="eeee">aaaaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="eeee">aaaaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="eeee">aaaaaa</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: The space is likely not on your LI's but rather on your UL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `padding-right: 0;` on your `ul`

```
.menu {
    padding-right: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
.menu{
}
```

to

```
.menu{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `padding:0` to your `ul` element:

```
ul.menu {
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W44ay/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this reset css

```
/*limited reset*/
html, body, div, section, article, aside, header, hgroup, footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, address, time, span, em, strong, img, ol, ul, li, figure, canvas, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The spacing may, in general, be caused by default margin or padding settings on the `ul` element or on the `li` elements. To clear them all (as seems to be appropriate here), set

```
.menu, .menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If e.g. some spacing is desired before or after the menu, set that separately after the above rule, e.g. `.menu { margin-bottom: 1em }`,